# Using storyboard different layouts xcode - outlet dont work

Tags: xcode, swift, storyboard

I am designing layout for iphones and for tablets using the Any * Compact and Regular * Regular of the Xcode story board

The problem is that outlets that i created in the iphones screen dont work in the tablets screens

Its like they are not connected and if i drag and connect them again to code it will work for the new connected layout devices but not on the old ones

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

If you use Any Any your outlets and elements on Storyboard will be available to all layouts, when you start qualifying device or layout sizing then the elements on that layout will only be available in that size.

Answer (score 1):

Make all the general configuration that will be same for all screens in Any Any . Then from that configure specific alterations that are needed for Iphones in landscape , portrait and Ipad landscape and portrait respectively